# Clarifications related to getting the total number of records in an aerospike set? Is Lua scripting needed?

Tags: python, lua, aerospike

I would like to get the total number of records in an aerospike set via python.
I guese, it is the value that is shown against n_objects against a set in the output of `show sets` -

```
aql> show sets
+-----------+------------------+----------------+-------------------+----------------+---------------------+--------------------------------------------+------------+
| n_objects | disable-eviction | set-enable-xdr | stop-writes-count | n-bytes-memory | ns_name             | set_name                                   | set-delete |
+
| 179       | "true"           | "use-default"  | 0                 | 0              | "namespace"         | "setName"                        | "false"    |
```

From what I read from this, it seems it is only possible via lua scripting - 
https://discuss.aerospike.com/t/fastest-way-to-count-records-returned-by-a-query/2379/4

Can someone confirm the same?
I am however able to find the count by using a counter variable by iterating over the result of `select()` and it is matching against the above count -

```
client = aerospike.client(config).connect()

scan = client.scan('namespace', 'set')

scan.select('PK','expiresIn','clientId','scopes','roles') 
scan.foreach(process_result)
print "Total aeroCount"
print aeroCount


def process_result((key, metadata, record)):
    global aeroCount
    aeroCount=aeroCount+1
```

**Update**

I tried running command `asinfo -v sets` on command line first. It gave me the objects count as well, like this -

`ns=namespace:set=setName:objects=29949:`.

Not sure how exactly to get the objects count against a set from this. Does this command qualify as a command for the python function? I tried this -

```
client = aerospike.client(config).connect()
response = client.info_all("asinfo -v sets")
```

Here is an error I am getting -

```
  File "Sandeepan-oauth_token_cache_complete_sanity_cp.py", line 89, in <module>
    response = client.info_all("asinfo -v sets")
AttributeError: 'aerospike.Client' object has no attribute 'info_all'
```

Comment: Use the info commands to find metrics about the cluster, namespaces, and sets.  Since I answered that discussion forum post, it was referring to queries, which aren't the same thing. A scan uses the primary index, where a query uses an optional secondary index. At this point in time I'd recommend a different way to count(*) what's in a query, by the way. See the original discussion forum post.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look into https://www.aerospike.com/apidocs/python/client.html?highlight=info#aerospike.Client.info_all  - info_all() in the python client and pass the correct info command from the info command reference here: https://www.aerospike.com/docs/reference/info

The `sets` info command gives you instantaneous stats such as number of objects in a specified set.

```
$ python
>>> import aerospike
>>> aerospike.__version__
'2.1.2'
>>> config = {'hosts':[("127.0.0.1", 3000)]}
>>> client = aerospike.client(config).connect()
>>> client.info("sets")
{'BB9BE1CFE290C00': (None, 'ns=test:set=testMap:objects=1:tombstones=0:memory_data_bytes=0:truncate_lut=0:stop-writes-count=0:set-enable-xdr=use-default:disable-eviction=false;\n')}
```

Comment: I think I would need some more help with the documentation here. Not sure of the format of the command, with reference to python client function info_all. I am not getting much clarity from the docs..

Comment: I did a quick test with an older python client that I have: >>> client.info("sets")
{'BB9BE1CFE290C00': (None, 'ns=test:set=testMap:objects=1:tombstones=0:memory_data_bytes=0:truncate_lut=0:stop-writes-count=0:set-enable-xdr=use-default:disable-eviction=false;\n')} ... you get the dictionary back - you can parse for objects >>> aerospike.__version__
'2.1.2'.

Comment: is there any way to get the values at set level, e.g.  n_objects`, other than using regex?